# How to access a Component.ts from another Component.ts (in the same app.component.html)

Tags: angular

I have this code that creates 3 `SectionComponent` inside `app.component.html`.

```
     <div *ngFor="let section of sectionObjectList">
        <app-section [section]="section" ></app-section>
      </div>
```

Now, from a `SectionComponent.ts` (class) I need to access the other `SectionComponent.ts` (class), to minipulate the fields and call functions inside them.

How can I do it? What's the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feom what you have written i can say that you can use @output in the section component and then that event can be captured in the app component and based upon that the values of array coupd be changes
And if you dont want to use @Output
The besy way will be link the functions to the service and that emit subject when changes are made which can be subscribed in the app component

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. In the meanwhile I used eventEmitter triggered by a sectionComponent and subscribed by other secitonComponent (in order to access fields and functions inside the latter one).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share codes, then logically they belong to service. Move the reusable code to service and you can access from multiple components.

Comment: Hi, I dont' want to share code. The code inside the component is the same, since i'm looping the same component. What I want to do is access component[2].ts from component[1].ts, access component[3].ts from component[2].ts and so on